# How do I add a calendar task to the default calendar in android?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I know you can add calendar events to Google Calendar using [CalendarContract.Events](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html) class but what I am interested in is adding a task object to the calendar instead. Tasks and events differ, seeing as a task only has a due date and a title. I see the option to add a task when opening Google calendar on my Android device:

[image]

But after searching through the Android documentation I have not found any class specific to handling calendar tasks. Does anyone know more about this? Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/quickstart/android

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the interface for adding a task on google calendar, also this documentation shows how to do it on different devices https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/106237?hl=en .

Comment: Just saw the API you posted @RandykaYudhistira, so is there no dedicated class in Android to do the job?

Comment: hmm,, i think there is no class for that. but the api is simple enough to call it with httprequest

Comment: Okay thanks for your help.